# Not being able to write output to text file in JAVA

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to output the squares of the numbers 1-10 to a file named Squares but i'm having an error with the `OutputStream.print(i+"\t"+(i*i));` part. The print is being underlined and i can't understand why. Please help me.

Here's the codes:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Number1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Squares.txt");
        PrintWriter square;

        try{
            square = new PrintWriter(fos);     
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Could not create/open file");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            OutputStream.print(i+"\t"+(i*i));
        }
    }
}
```

Complete solution:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Number1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Squares.txt");
   PrintWriter square = null; 

   try{
       square = new PrintWriter(fos);     

   }

   catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.out.print("Could not create/open file");
       System.exit(0);
   }

   for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
   {
      square.print(i+"\t"+(i*i));
   }
  square.close();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OutputStream` has no `print` method ,and even if it had one, it would probably not be a static method.

Use your `PrintWriter` instance to write to the file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Squares.txt");
    try{           
        PrintWriter square = new PrintWriter(fos);     
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            square.print(i+"\t"+(i*i));
        }
        square.close ();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Could not create/open file");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the output stream needs to be flushed or closed so data is written to the file :)

Comment: Lol Now i was wondering why the data was not written to the file. I'm new to files. Thanks i'll close it now.

Comment: PrintWriter square = new PrintWriter(fos); never throws Exception. This FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Squares.txt"); throw Exception first

Comment: @Tkachuk_Evgen The main method already has a `throws FileNotFoundException`, so `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Squares.txt")` doesn't have to be in the try block.

Comment: @Eran And what is the reason to surround PrintWriter square = new PrintWriter(fos);  with try{}catch? In JavaDoc PrintWriter(OutputStream out) not throwing Exceptions?

Comment: @Tkachuk_Evgen Well, it's possible the code posted by the OP is part of longer code that may throw exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `square.print(i+"\t"+(i*i));` instead of `OutputStream.print(i+"\t"+(i*i));`

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `print` on the class `OutputStream` rather than on an instance of a class that has that function. What you probably want to do is

```
square.print(i+"\t"+(i*i));
```

Answer (score 3):

To quickly make your code to work,

move the for loop into the `try{}` statement, and also instead of wrongly calling the `OutputStream.print`, use the command: `square.print`

Answer (score -1):

You should use `fos.write((i+"\t"+(i*i)).getBytes());`

Comment: Do elaborate on the answer